# Go through a process addresses - Python

Tags: python

I'm thinking of creating a program that does the same function as the Cheat Engine, but in Python. I carry a running process step and a value, then the program goes through each memory address of the process and sees the value hits, then filters the hitting. After I pass another value and it traverses these filtered and verifies addresses which are equal ... then repeats this until about a few addresses ...

Well, I already know how I'll do the first time I will have to go through all the addresses, but how do I do it? Since we do not know what the last address ...

Note: I'm using `ctypes` to read the value of the addresses.

Comment: You need to read the other process' memory, not your own, and that is platform dependent. What platform are you on?

Comment: Then you need to use the OpenPrcess and ReadProcessMemory win32api for that. Look for them in SO, I'm sure someone has already detailed on how to do that (prob. even in python too).